# How can fragments obtain their activity's GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

My main activity has a Google Maps v2 map fragment, and one other fragment that gets replaced as the user navigates the workflow.  The activity obtains the GoogleMap instance using the recommended double-checked approach.  The fragments all need to manipulate the map instance, adding markers and/or camera change listeners.  So... **how can the fragments reliably obtain a reference to the map?**  (Or, in general, any non-`Parcelable` thing that belongs to the activity?)

Recommended pattern:

Fragments are supposed communicate with each other via the activity.  Google recommends making the activity implement some interface that the fragments can call back to.  So say I give my activity a `getMap()` method that the fragments will call when they're added to the activity, and only create and add the fragments after the map has been initialized.

Will this approach work even when the activity is destroyed and recreated by the framework, e.g., when the device is rotated?  I guess my doubt is whether fragments will always be recreated by my activity's `onCreate()`/`onResume()`, or whether fragments might sometimes be recreated by some framework voodoo, leaving them without a valid map instance.  (Fragments *are* sometimes created by voodoo, right?  I think that's why they're not supposed to have explicit constructors.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem.  It seems to work even with "don't keep activities" checked in developer options.  I'd still appreciate hearing if this solution is good, bad, or weird.

It seems that no matter how the fragment is re-created and attached, the activity's map will have been obtained (if it's going to be obtained) by the time the fragment's `onResume()` is called.

```
public class FooFragment extends Fragment {
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MainActivity a = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        map = a.map;
        if(map != null) {
            // TODO register listeners
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(map != null) {
            // TODO unregister listeners
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the activity's `initMap()`, called in both `onCreate()` and `onResume()`:

```
private void initMap() {
    if(map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if(map != null) {
            // TODO configure map
            setFragment(); // attaches the appropriate fragment
        }
    }
}
```